# I am using ajax get. Response in controller is correct but in ajax get return 404 error

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

java script is:

```
function LogOn() {

var sendData = "userName=" + UserName.value + "&password=" + Password.value + "&isRemember=" + isRemember.checked;

$.get('../Account/LogIn', sendData, function (Data, status, jqXHR) {

    if (Data.IsSuccess == 1) {
       alert('ok');
    }
}, 'Json').fail(function () {
    MessageError.removeAttribute('hidden');
    MessageError.innerHTML = "خطای سمت سرور ";
})
}
```

in controller httpclient return correct result. but when javascript ajax return resoinse, return 404 error.
controler account is:

```
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    int isSuccess = 1;
    object _Result = null;

    try 
    { 
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };

        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string username = Request["userName"].ToString();
        string password = Request["password"].ToString();
        string encryptPass = JJorianClassLibrery.DLL.Encryptions.Encrypt(password, Entity.EncryptKey);

        bool isRemember = bool.Parse(Request["isRemember"]);

        var response = client.GetAsync(GetBaseUrl() + "api/v1/User/Login/" + username + "/" + encryptPass).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            isSuccess = 1;
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            _Result = result;
        }
        else
        {
            _Result = "نام کاربری یا کلمه عبور نادرست است";
            isSuccess = 0;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        isSuccess = 0;
        _Result = "عملیات ورود با موفقیت انجام نشد";
    }

    return Json(new { IsSuccess = isSuccess, Message = _Result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

in controller response is correct and return json of result, but when pass result to javascript,get ajax ret response is 404(not found)...

Comment: How do you know that the controller is returning the correct result? If it returns a 404 is because it cannot find your controller... The url you are attacking ('../Account/LogIn') is very suspicious, how have you mapped your controller to the url?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very simple, your link to the controller is wrong...

try this:

```
$.get('/Account/LogIn', sendData, function (Data, status, jqXHR)
```

Answer (score 0):

the 404 error means the ajax call didn't find the controller.

```
$.get('../Account/LogIn', sendData, function (Data, status, jqXHR)
```

are you sure ('../Account/LogIn') is valid? maybe you're going to need the file extension(.php, .js, etc) or maybe the entire file path for example ('http://yourdomain.com/Account/LogIn.php')

hope this help